# Explanation of the different variable types in statistics?

Tags: categorical-data, computational-statistics, descriptive-statistics, discrete-data

One thing that has always tripped me up when trying to learn new methods in statistics is understanding what type of features/variables can this method be applied to.

The variable types that especially trip me up are

- Discrete
- Continuous
- Categorical
- Nominal
- Ordinal

What are some examples and simple explanations of these and other commonly used variables types.

Comment: You could get explanations and examples of the different variable types from any introductory statistics book. Also see [this](http://www.andrews.edu/~calkins/math/edrm611/edrm01.htm#DATA_TYPE) and [this](http://www.abs.gov.au/websitedbs/a3121120.nsf/home/statistical+language+-+what+are+variables) links for brief explanations and examples.

Comment: I think there are  only two type of  variables in statistics (continuous and discrete, or some people may say three, continuous and discrete).  Categorical, nominal and ordinal are all discrete, Categorical may include nominal and ordinal, while nominal has no order (or rank), ordinal has some order or (rank). The Quantative and Qualitative classification is really confusing (at least to me). I think Qualitative is also Quantative in statistics.

Comment: @DeepNorth I used to think quantitative meant that there was some continuous function with the data but it looks like this only applies to regressive data.

Comment: [Stevens' *level of measurement* typology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_measurement) is commonly used (and the division in this question is partly based on that one); in that typology discrete numeric variates are either ratio or interval, but in statistics they're generally treated differently from continuous ratio or interval variates. (That typology and the one in your question are also not the only way to divide up variable "types")

Comment: This question is misguided, I am afraid.  It is a mistake to use Stevens' typology to decide whether or not a statistical method can be applied to data.  This can--and does--seem to rule out powerful, appropriate methods (such as Poisson regression for continuous responses).  It misleads people into thinking that selecting a statistical procedure is merely a matter of figuring out a variable "type." It also has misled many into overlooking the rich, complex variety of data, ranging from counts to differences to proportions to sounds to images and more, that don't fit into this classification.

Comment: @whuber I understand what you are saying, for example the other day I got really confused by a version of Naive Bayes specifically meant for text classification, but at the end of the day aren't these things different data \types eventually broken down into these variable ty]=

Answer (score 7):

I was able to find a diagram from [this](http://www.abs.gov.au/websitedbs/a3121120.nsf/home/statistical+language+-+what+are+variables) page that clarified a lot of the original confusion.

[image]

- A **continuous variable** is a numeric variable. Observations can take any
  value between a certain set of real numbers (height, age, temperature, ect..)
- A **discrete variable** is a numeric variable that only consist of integers (number of kids, cars, pets,ect...)
- An **ordinal variable** is a categorical variable that can be ranked (grades,pizza size,levels of satisfaction)
- A **nominal variable** is a categorical variable that can't be ranked
  (race,religion, sex)

Comment: That is very nice. That is what I often use to describe variable types.

Comment: Stevens actually defined these variables differently, in terms of the groups of mathematical transformations that could be applied to them. Tukey, a short time later, thought it important to emphasize the fact that measurement type should not be considered a determiner of the form of statistical analysis. For instance, Tukey (and others) developed powerful techniques to analyze ordinal data as if they were continuous. Also note that this sense of "discrete" is much narrower than recognized by statistical theory: it seems to be describing *count* data. What happened to Stevens' *ratio* type?

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing variable types with variable qualities
Think of variables as a collection of qualities:
{ordered, unordered}
{discrete, continuous}
{fininte, infinite}
{known, unknown} (in terms of numeric value)

Categorical - {{discrete},{unordered},{finite}}
Ordinal - {{discrete},{ordered},{finite,infinite},{known,unknown}}
Numeric -{{discrete,continuous},{ordered},{known}}

Comment: Nominal is synonymous for Categorical and Qualitative

Comment: Numeric is synonymous for Quantitative, and is sometimes called Continuous

Comment: Ordinals are indexed by integers; that is the number you care about.